# How is this validation error possible for this code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

The error is `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Route must exist`.

This is the code:

```
new_route = Route.create!(new_route_data)

new_points.each_with_index do |point, index|
  new_point_data = { route_id: new_route.id,
                     latitude: point[0],
                     longitude: point[1],
                     timestamp: point[2] }
  new_point = Point.create!(new_point_data)
end
```

It is being reported for the `new_point = Point.create!(new_point_data)` line.

Related Details:

- This code is running in a single Sidekiq worker as you see it above (so, the Route isn't being created in one worker, with the Points being created in another worker - this is all inline)
- The `routes` table has almost 3M records
- The `points` table has about 2.5B records
- The `Point` model contains `belongs_to :route, counter_cache: true`
- There are no validations on the `Route` model
- In case it's relevant, the `Route` model does contain `belongs_to :user, counter_cache: true`
- There are only about 5k records in the `users` table

Software versions:

- Rails 5.1.5
- Ruby 2.5.0
- PostgreSQL 9.6.7

Comment: do you need to make this assignment? `new_point = Point.create!(new_point_data)`... could you try doing just `Point.create!(new_point_data)` and set `route: new_route` instead of `route_id: new_route.id` in `new_point_data`

Comment: yeah I second the above. If your validation inside `Point` is `validates :route, presence: true` then you should pass the attribute as `route: new_route` not `route_id: new_route.id` because the validation is on `route`, and not `route_id`

Comment: I'll try referencing `activity` directly instead of `activity.id` & follow up here after monitoring a bit (could be some days). I'm using `new_point.id` later on, which is why I (think I) need to make that assignment.

Comment: It's possible that Sidekiq is too fast and new_route has not been committed to the db yet before it tries to access it. You might want to make sure new_route.id is available before the assignment.

Comment: @EJ2015 Could this really be _sidekiq_ being too fast, though? It's just ruby code at this point - all happening within a single process. Wouldn't I expect these errors _anywhere_ this code appeared in my Rails app, if it was a matter of `new_route` not being committed to the db yet?

Comment: @JamesChevalier yes I meant maybe it's not committed to the db yet. You can check if that's the case with some logging.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code does not make sense. You are iterating **new_point** and assigning **new_point** to some value in the block. So I am assuming that you meant iteration over some collection called data_points

Try this.

In Route model

```
has_many :points
```

then:

```
new_route = ...
data_points.each do |point|
  point_data = {latitude: point[0], ...}   # do not include route_id
  new_route.points.create(point_data) # idiomatic
end
```

`
You don't need the index, so don't use each_with_index.

Comment: Oops! You're right - I'm fixing that `each` call now.... I'm iterating over `new_points` to create individual `new_point` objects...

Comment: Aghk - I _am_ also using `index` in my real code. It's a really wonky data structure that I didn't want to get into here... Sorry for the additional confusion!

Comment: Your main point here is to switch from `Point.create!` to `new_route.points.create` (because I do already have the `has_many` on the `Route` model)... Now I'm interested in the differences between the two...

Answer (score 0):

It's tough to say what the issue is without seeing what type of validations you have in the Point model.

My guess is that your validation in point.rb is:

`validates :route, presence: true`

With ActiveRecord relations, you can use this shortcut to avoid explicitly assigning route_id:

```
new_point_data = { latitude: point[0],longitude: point[1], timestamp: point[2] }
new_route.points.create!(new_point_data)
```

where new_point data does not have route_id.

You should also rename the new_point that you are assigning in the block since you are writing over the array that you're iterating.

Comment: There are no validations on the `Point` model.